# iOS crash 'failed to exit on time'

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to get some input into this crash that is happening on some ios devices. This is a unity project and the crash happens when I switch scene. From the crash logs it seems like the app was killed by the watchdog process, but it's unclear why? The CPU loads seems fine to me. It happens when we are switching scenes in the game, but when I test on the same hardware it works fine.

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 10.480 (user 9.980, system 0.000), 67% CPU Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 6.617, 43% CPU
Application Specific Information:
com.test.test failed to exit in time

Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Comment: This usually means something is blocking on the main thread for too long.

Comment: Yup, watchdog kills unresponsive apps/processes after about 10 seconds. This is also the case when loading from the appdelegate takes too long. A workaround is to show a splash scene and perform the load of a complex scene from there.